# iOS (Swift) Singleton Realm Object

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, singleton, realm

After reading [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/81615/introduction-to-realm) tutorial I need some assistance in understanding what the most efficient way to do the following.

When my app is opened, it needs to load a `Profile` object. Since there should only be one of these in the lifetime of the app I set it up to be a singleton.

Realm seemed to be a great way to save and retrieve data. Upon further viewing it seems I need to have a data model in order to use Realms. After a failed attempt of integrating `Object` into the Profile.swift shown below I need some assistance in how I should handle this issue. Should I make a second class `ProfileDataModel` that can be called by `Profile` to retrieve and save changes, or is there a way to include a Realm `Object` into a Singleton class?

Profile.swift

```
class Profile {

    //MARK: Singleton
    static let sharedInstance = Profile()

    //MARK: Properties
    var characterName: String
    var level: Int

    //MARK: Init
    private init() {
        //TODO: Load from realms
        self.characterName = "John Appleseed"
        self.level = 50
    }

    //MARK: Helper Methods
    static func save(){
        //TODO: Save to Realm
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you to create a db manager class to handle all db operations on it, then you can create your data models separately and use your manager class to fetch/store data on your db.

```
class DBManager {
//MARK: Singleton
static let sharedInstance = DBManager()

//MARK: Init
private override init(){
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: dbPath,
        readOnly: false)
    do{
        myDB = try Realm(configuration: config)
        print(dbPath)
    }
    catch{
        print("boooom")
    }

}

    //retrive data from db
    func getDataFromDB() -> Results<DataModel>{
    let results: Results<NewsModel> = myDB.objects(DataModel)
    return results
    }

    //write an object in db
    func addDataModelEntry(object: DataModel){
        try! myDB.write{
            myDB.add(object, update: true)
        }
    }

}

//your controller you want to use your db manager class
class main(){ 
    func viewDidLoad(){
       DBManager.sharedInstance.getDataFromDB() ///here you have realm results

       DBManager.sharedInstance.addDataModelEntry(customDataModel) //to store your object on db
    }
}
```

i put some samples just to show the way of doing, you can use these functions to extend to any kind of db operations for your specific needs.

Comment: Thats the way I use to do it as well. At leat in smaller apps, this is a good way to go to keep track of the code accessing the Realm. Also you could rather easily exchange the underlying database to e.g. Core Data if necessary (hopefully not)

Comment: @brainray how do you do it currently or in bigger apps?

Comment: @sirvon, this approach works fine already. 
or in big projects, if this is not fine to use, you can directly use write blocks where you are handling requests. 
when data are fetched, directly write them to Realm with write block, and for updating UI, in each VC, add related notification for realm objects to update it.
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications

Answer (score 3):

As you already suggested, it wouldn't be a very good idea to implement the Singleton pattern on a Realm managed object. These are bound to a thread and can be only modified from write transactions.

Instead if you need shared mutable global state and want to persist that within Realm, I'd recommend to have a class which allows you to retrieve objects, which only act in the purpose of describing the persisted data. E.g. a `DatabaseManager` as a singleton, which instantiates a new Realm and returns the single existing `Profile` object, inheriting from `Object` but without custom `static` properties or methods.

Comment: More or less, the singleton method gives you threading issues. Although in one of my project even if I performed a simple object fetch with the primary key in a file (not using singleton), it also gives lots of crashes with the Realm.